# Is the MySQL JSON data type bad for performance for data retrieval?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, json

Let's say I have a MySQL JSON data type called `custom_properties` for a media table:

[image]

An example of the json data stored in the `custom_properties` column could be:

```
{
 "company_id": 1, 
 "uploaded_by": "Name", 
 "document_type": "Policy", 
 "policy_signed_date": "04/04/2018"
}
```

In my PHP Laravel app I would do something like this:

```
$media = Media::where('custom_properties->company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

This would fetch all media items belonging to company 1.

My question is that lets say we have 1 million media records, would this be a bad way to fetch records in terms of performance? Can anyone shed some light on how MySQL indexes JSON data types?

From the [MySQL official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html):

> JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal
>   format that permits quick read access to document elements. When the
>   server later must read a JSON value stored in this binary format, the
>   value need not be parsed from a text representation. The binary format
>   is structured to enable the server to look up subobjects or nested
>   values directly by key or array index without reading all values
>   before or after them in the document.

Comment: Show us the `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 9):

So I've made some tests with big data; I created these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `json` (
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

the first table is storing its data in a JSON field, the other uses columns.

I filled each table with **1,000,000 records**.

I ran these two queries:

```
select * from users where relation_id > 100 order by relation_id limit 100


select json_extract(data, '$.name') as name,
       json_extract(data, '$.relation_id') as relation_id
       from json
        where json_extract(data, '$.relation_id') > 100 order by relation_id
        limit 100
```

The first query, which queries the table that **does not** use JSON, results in

`[2022-03-02 00:37:46] 100 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 854 ms (execution: 838 ms, fetching: 16 ms)`

the second query which **uses JSON**, results in:

`[2022-03-02 00:42:52] 100 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 1 s 10 ms (execution: 994 ms, fetching: 16 ms)`

so obviously it is not that much different in simple cases.

now trying to run aggregate functions, these two queries:

```
select name, relation_id, description , max(relation_id) as max_relation
from users
where relation_id > 100
group by name, relation_id, description
order by relation_id
limit 100; # executed in 5 s 3 ms

select data -> '$.name'             as name,
       data -> '$.relation_id'      as relation_id,
       data -> '$.description'      as description,
       max(data -> '$.relation_id') as max_relation
from json
where json_extract(data, '$.relation_id') > 100
group by data -> '$.name', data -> '$.relation_id', data -> '$.description'
order by relation_id
limit 100 # executed in 6 s 238 ms
```

The first query results in:

```
[2022-03-02 15:23:13] 100 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 5 s 21 ms (execution: 5 s 3 ms, fetching: 18 ms)
```

The second query results in:

```
[2022-03-02 15:23:25] 100 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 6 s 238 ms (execution: 6 s 218 ms, fetching: 20 ms)
```

so looks like there is a noticeable performance difference when using aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these tests, i would be very curious about running the same tests using generated columns (virtual) and having an index on `relation_id` for example

Answer (score 4):

I think we can safely assume the performance would be worse than using regular columns.

The way to index JSON attributes is to create a virtual generated column for the particular attribute you want (company_id), then index the virtual column, and use that column to filter your query.